# How to prove one specific condition

Tags: number-theory

For a positive integer $n$, the equation $x^2=n+y^2$, $x,y$ integers does not have a solution if and only if

(a) $n=2$

(b) $n$ is a prime number

(c) $n$ is an odd number

(d) $n$ is an even number not divisible by $4$

I think answer should be $n$ is an even number not divisible by $4$, for then we will have $(x+y)(x-y)=2(2K+1)$ which is impossible. Please verify?

Comment: Your answer is correct, and you have shown the "if", but you have not shown the "only if".

Comment: @Joe. Yes. But if this were on a multiple-choice test you would choose (d) based on just the "if" and go  to the next Q.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, yes, of course, which is why I started my comment by "Your answer is correct", but since the title asked "how to prove one specific question", I thought the OP might want to know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If you want to prove the "only if" part, meaning that the equation does not have a solution only if $n \equiv 2$ mod $4$, then you need to show that it does have a solution if $n$ is odd or $n$ is divisible by 4.

To do that, when $n$ is odd, try letting $(x-y)=1$, and solving for $y$ in terms of $k$, in the equation $1(1+2y)=2k+1$.

When when $n$ is divisible by 4, try letting $(x-y)=2$, and solving for $y$ in terms of $k$, in the equation $2(2+2y)=4k$.